# Multi level IF statement

Tags: groovy

I am wanting to create a multi level IF statement.  The statement below is IF it is "Red Flagged" else do the else clause.  What I want is more IF statements.  How do I say IF "Red Flagged" or IF "Open" or IF "Active" or ELSE?  Is this a GROOVY IF or is this a JAVA command?

```
                        CellStyle statusStyle = wb.createCellStyle()
                        statusStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND)
                        if (it.MOPSTATUS.equals("Red Flagged")) {
                            statusStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new HSSFColor.RED().getIndex())
                        } else {
                            statusStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new HSSFColor.WHITE().getIndex())
                        }
```

Comment: I suggest you visit the Java tutorial and there should be some helpful guide there for learning about these language basics.

Comment: Can you post a link to these tutorials?

Comment: If you search for "Oracle The Java Tutorials" it will probably come up first. Check out the "Learning the Java Language" thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something different depending on the value, do as follows

```
if (it.MOPSTATUS.equals("Red Flagged")) {
    statusStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new HSSFColor.RED().getIndex())
} else if (it.MOPSTATUS.equals("Open")) {
    // DO SOMETHING
} else if () {
    // DO SOMETHING ELSE
} else {
    statusStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new HSSFColor.WHITE().getIndex())
}
```

otherwise, this shall suffice

```
if (it.MOPSTATUS.equals("Red Flagged")
        || it.MOPSTATUS.equals("Open")
        || it.MOPSTATUS.equals("Active"))
{
    statusStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new HSSFColor.RED().getIndex())
} else {
    statusStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new HSSFColor.WHITE().getIndex())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as in Java

```
if (it.MOPSTATUS.equals("Red Flagged") ||
    it.MOPSTATUS.equals("open") ) {
    statusStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new HSSFColor.RED().getIndex())
} else {
    statusStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new HSSFColor.WHITE().getIndex())
}
```

Or for different outcomes per possibility

```
if (it.MOPSTATUS.equals("Red Flagged") ) {
    // something
} else if ( it.MOPSTATUS.equals("open") ) {
    // something else
} else {
    statusStyle.setFillForegroundColor(new HSSFColor.WHITE().getIndex())
}
```